# Different Font sizes in Sidebar

Tags: css

I have different Font sizes in my Sidebar.
The Link is: http://ntm.at/r0sa/
You can see it in "Partners/Links",
Partners is smaller than Links.
And some Letters are bigger then the others.
i use Arial, Font-size 0.8em . 
Can someone explain this?
Thank you in advance,
Rosa

Comment: please post relevant html and css code so we can find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "partner" is wrapped inside `span` element with class `caps`, which has `font-size` set to `90%`. Change it (remove class, remove span, or wrapp whole link inside `span`) and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for helping me... but i can only edit the CSS, not the HTML. Where can i find span/caps in css? searched with firebug but didn`t find it

Comment: Well, those are inline's. Line 77, in your `head` section. You can override it in your external stylesheet with no problem.

Comment: Oh no, I answered too quick, because it works only with firebug...I think i am too stupid to find the head section or "caps". the site is made with wordpress. i only find "Header", not "Head". In my Stylesheet there is no head-section, i searched everything with notepad. with firebug it works great, but there it says it`s in the "inline" section, or in the "r0sa"- line 78 section...

Comment: Ok, in your external stylesheet file (your css file) add: `span.caps {font-size: 100%;}` - this should help.